# Dynamical increase JTable size

Tags: java, swing

I have a matrix that is always square, and I made a JTable to display its contents. I need the JTable to adjust its number of rows/columns to match the matrix.
The method I'm using adjusts the numbers of rows show on the table, but the number of columns stays the same. Why is that? And how should I do it then?

The code bellow is missing methods that are not relevant to this question. The matrix is being updated as it should be, I checked.

```
public class SomeClass{

    TableModel tableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return matrix.lines.size()+1;
                }

                public int getRowCount() {
                    return matrix.lines.size()+1;
                }

                public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                    Object val = "+";

                    if(row == 0 && col == 0)
                        return " ";

                    if(row == 0) {
                        try {
                            val = matrix.lines.get(0).cells.get(col-1).nodeId;
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            val = "-";
                        }
                        return val;
                    }

                    if(col == 0) {
                        try {
                            val = matrix.lines.get(row-1).nodeId;
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            val = "-";
                       }
                        return val;
                    }


                    try {
                        val = (int)observer.nodeList.get(id).matrix.lines.get(row-1).cells.get(col-1).dist;
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        val = "-";
                    }

                    return val;
                 }

           };


    public void updateTable(){
        //STUFF HERE
    }
}
```

The `updateTable` method is called after the matrix is updated. I have tried a couple of implementations for this method, with mixed results, presented below.

**Implementation 1**

```
public void updateTable(){
        ((AbstractTableModel) table.table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

Result: The number of rows is updated, but the number of columns stays the same.

**Implementation 2**

```
public void updateTable(){
        ((AbstractTableModel) table.table.getModel()).fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
```

Result: Works, most of the time... Both dimensions are updated, but an exception is thrown occasionally:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2012)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: In theory, `fireTableStructureChanged` should cause the `JTable` to receate/populate the `TableModel` from the values from the `TableModel`. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You also shouldn't be calling `fireTableStructureChanged` from outside of the context of the model, why these methods are public is beyond me, you should be asking the implementation to reset itself and trigger the event itself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have updated my question. I still tried calling fireTableStructureChanged, just to see what happened, result are in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to update the model (or the matrix) from out side of the context of event dispatching thread

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom `TableModel` extending `AbstractTableModel` you are responsible for firing the proper `TableModel` events ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)).

That means that when your `matrix` is changed by adding/deleting columns, you should call [`fireTableStructureChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged--) (from within the `AbstractTableModel` subclass).

If the `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` property of the JTable is true, the `JTable` will discard any table columns that it had and reallocate default columns in the order they appear in the model.

That means that your updateTable method should read:

```
public void updateTable()
{
  fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

Comment: The `TableEvent` with the `row` of value of `TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW` triggers a "structure" changed event, which would, if the `JTable` is configured to do so (which it is by default), recreate the `ColumnModel` based on the values of the `TableModel`, which is basically the same as changing the `JTable`'s model.  This can be achieved by simply using `AbstractTableModel#fireTableStructureChanged`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't wanna spread misinformation... What you're saying is that my answer is basically not correct? Or that it's incomplete?

Comment: Kind of, by default, the `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` property of `JTable` is `true`, this means if you change the `TableModel` (`setModel`) or the `TableModel` fires a `stuctureChanged` event, then it should repopulate the columns based on the columns of the model. The fact is, I don't know if the `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` has been changed, that would account for the fact that the columns aren't been updated, but it could be caused by something else, there's simply not enough context to the question to know why. The `matrix`might be at fault, wrong reference or not been updated as expected

Comment: ^--- Add some of that to your answer :P

Comment: @TT. The method you suggest throws exceptions occasionally, with origins I have not been able to identify.

Comment: @AmiguelS What I outlined is what the JAVA specifications expect for the setup you described. Alas without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there isn't much we can do to help you in your situation.

Comment: note fireTableStructureChanged reseting (almost)all custom properties from JTables view/XxxTableModel,